# Compare vectors to find the closest one to a given vector.

Tags: vector-spaces

What is the best way to compare a set of 3D vectors and find out what vector is the closest in direction to a given vector?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Recall that the dot product of two vectors is $v\cdot u=|v||u|\sin(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between them, so if you normalise the vectors to remove the $|v||u|$ coefficient, their dot product is a good comparison.